# Cannot start xampp mysql server (already change port other than 3306)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, port

I try starting the xampp mysql service and i failed. I already disable mysql service in the windows service panel and i change the ports 3306 to 3309 in the my.ini file.

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3309                                      // change here
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3309                                                // change here
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

However, it stills say that

```
5:56:19 PM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
5:56:19 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "C:\mysql_community_server\bin\mysqld MySQL"!
5:56:19 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:56:19 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:56:19 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Logs：

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Question:

1. Why I change to port 3309 and it is still connecting to the port 3306?
2. I already disable other mysql service so even though it is 3306 and it should still able to connect

Comment: it cannot started @MarkoMackic

Comment: C:\mysql_community_server\bin\mysqld  This is a processes that is using the port as you can see, go into task manager, find it and kill it, or find some script to kill process running on particular port

Comment: it still not working @MarkoMackic

Comment: Is the log still the same

Comment: I edit the question @MarkoMackic

Comment: so it's shutted down, now start it up, and please check where you connect with php to it, address and port are correct

Comment: start up what ? @MarkoMackic

Comment: mysql server, mariadb I don't know what do you have

Comment: that is the problem, i cannot start up in xampp @MarkoMackic